# Fabric.js loadFromJSON() method undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

I have wrote this function in a class:

```
this.loadCanvas = function(json) {
    // parse the data into the canvas
    stage.loadFromJSON(json);

    // re-render the canvas
    stage.renderAll();
}
```

Where stage is new fabric object.

But in the browser it is showing this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'loadFromJSON' of undefined
```

Please tell how can I solve this?

Comment: We'll need jsfiddle showing the error. Also, which Fabric version?

Comment: `loadFromJSON` only exists on `fabric.Canvas` and not on `fabric.Object`. Is `stage` defined? It looks like your stage object is undefined.